# Typo3 4.6 Backend language doesn't change after update

Tags: typo3, backend

I've just upgraded typo3 from 4.3.3 to 4.6.8.

Before, the language change in admin worked, but now, it doesn't, even with newly created users.

Any idea why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Extension Manager" -> "Language Packages". Select the languages you need on the left side, and click the button "Update from repository". In TYPO3 4.6 the language handling has been changed, so i think you need to update the language files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you out? http://bugs.typo3.org/view.php?id=11300

*Go to `User tools` > `User settings` > `Admin functions` and select the desired user from the `"Simulate backend user"` selectbox. Then after the user loads, just choose the appropriate `"Language"` from the `"Language & Personal data"` tab. Save it and you're good to go.*

*Or try deleting and reloading the translations.*